# I can't change the visibility of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view

I'm trying to change the visibility of the RecyclerView to `View.GONE`. However, no changes are taking place:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
            public void run() {
               list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
      if (list == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
      }
```

Here's the View:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/allUsers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_container" />
```

Removing `runOnUiThread` doesn't work, nor does `list.invalidate()`. Nothing is crashing. This is in an inner class. What  am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the layout?

Comment: @galex sure, just a sec

Comment: can you show where/how `list` variable is being assigned?

Comment: Can you confirm the QueryTextListener is set ?

Comment: @Vinodh turns out `list` wasn't `final`, and for some reason the project actually compiled. Will post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when you access a variable from an inner class, the compiler should say:

> Variable 'x' is accessed from an inner class, needs to be declared `final`

For some reason **I wasn't getting the comile-time error. Even though the variable was declared in a method.**

So make sure the variable you're accessing from the inner class is declared `final` like this:

```
final X y;
```

and not like this:

```
X y;
```

*Where `X` is the type and `y` is the name of the variable.*

See [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)

Comment: The variable doesn't need to be final if it's in the scope of the class which is seems to be here.